# Cross-domain request through $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jsonp

Consider the follwoing code :

```
$("#btn1").click( function() {      

     $.ajax({ 
       type: "GET",
       dataType:       'jsonp',
       jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',  
       url: myurl,

        success: getObj,

        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {

                    alert(xhr.statusText);

            alert(xhr.responseText);

            alert(xhr.status);

            alert(errorThrown);

                }           

    });
```

and the success function is

```
function getObj(data) {




    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

      alert( key + ": " + value );

        });
});
```

When i try the to access the url directly it returns the data like this:

```
[{"id":405,"parentId":404,"createdBy":"iipaxAdm","displayName":"A-2013-04-1""eventCount":"0"},{"id":601,"parentId":404,"createdBy":"iipaxAdm","displayName":"A-2013-04-2","eventCount":"0"},{"id":701,"parentId":404,"createdBy":"iipaxAdm","displayName":"A-2013-04-3","eventCount":"3"}]
```

But when traverse the data(return result) it only give the first result :

```
{"id":405,"parentId":404,"createdBy":"iipaxAdm","displayName":"A-2013-04-1""eventCount":"0"},
```

When checked in the developer tool the response contains the all  results.

How can make sure that data should contain all reslutls?

Answer (score -1):

Might be that the javascript thinks it is a string and not an object. Since it is JSON, you can use `JSON.parse(data)` to get the data as an object or array of objects, then traverse it.

Comment: if you use Chrome, you can use console.log() on the data that your trying to iterate through. It will show it as an object in a tree view, I recommend using this to debug why you are able to retrieve all the records. Also, maybe trying to iterate a different way:    `for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ alert(data[i].id); }`